# Impact of acidic water on house plumbing

Tags: plumbing, lead

My wife and I are considering purchasing a house.  The house was built in 1991 by the present owner.  The water comes from a well on the property.

As part of the inspection process, we had the kitchen tap analyzed for contamination.  The water used for the test was the first draw from the cold water after 8 hours of non-use (basically first thing in the morning).

The test (SM 3113B) showed 0.018 mg/l of lead, with a pH of 5.0.

I know nearly nothing about plumbing.  My reading suggests that most likely cause for the failed test is that the acidic water is dissolving the lead in the plumbing.  The owner wants to have a qualified plumber install a pH neutralizer and then flush the system and retest.

My questions:

1) Since this house was built after the Safe Drinking Water acts of 1986, what sources of lead exist in the plumbing of the house?  In other words, where was the acidic water attacking to cause the lead in the water? Brass fittings?

2) We believe the acidic water has flowed through the system for years.
Given that, even after the water is neutralized and the system is flushed, do we have to worry about particles of lead coming free (like rust in a corroded pipe)?

3) Again, given that the acidic water has flowed through the system for years, do we have to worry that any of the components have been sufficiently compromised that they have to be replaced or are likely to have an abnormally short life-span?

**Update:**

I am guessing that the original source of the problem is the acidic water.  My questions are primarily about whether the acidic water has done lasting harm even if the water's pH is now adjusted back to a more neutral level.

Comment: Units can get confusing, but 0.018 mg / L is 18 ppb which is above the EPA action level in drinking water (15 ppb). I think you are right to be hesitant to buy this house until you can determine if raising the pH of the water will reduce the level. https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/lead/tips/water.htm

Comment: I've seen some sites that suggest anything over 0.005 mg / L warrants putting in filtering.  My concern is that even if I filter at the water entry into the house, has the piping in the house been compromised by having the acidic water running through it for a long time...

Comment: You will of course need to get a sample of the well water after thorough flushing fir comparison. To rule out lead contamination in the well water.

Comment: I agree.  My concern is that even if I install a filtering system at the water's entry into the house, and get a clean test result at the kitchen tap, do I still need to worry about long term problems due to the damage already done to the system?  Do I need to worry that chips/flakes/particles of lead that were compromised by the acidic water will enter the water in the future even if the pH is now neutral?

Comment: You need to know more about the well ; maybe the lead is coming from it. What is the water source/ aquifer ?